# How do I create a new variable from the result of a for loop with an if else statement in it in python?

Tags: python

I have these temperatures:

```
temperatures = [-5.4, 1.0, -1.3, -4.8, 3.9, 0.1, -4.4]
```

This works as a statement, but I can't get this in to a variable:

```
for i in temperatures:
if i < -2:
    print('Cold')
elif i >= -2 and i <= 2:
    print('Slippery')
elif i >2 and i < 15:
    print('Comfortable')
else:
    print('Warm')
```

I know that the following code works to get a variable from a loop:

```
x = [i for i in range(21)]
print (x)
```

So I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
temp_class = [i for i in temperatures:
if i < -2:
    print('Cold')
elif i >= -2 and i <= 2:
    print('Slippery')
elif i >2 and i < 15:
    print('Comfortable')
else:
    print('Warm')]
```

But get this error:

File "", line 1
    temp_class = [i for i in temperatures:
                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What would be the correct code to:
1. Get a variable from my statement
2. Get both the temperatures and classes in a table similar to a tibble or data.frame in R.

Thanks

Comment: There is something strange with your code, if you enter `-2`, as temperature, it will print `'Warm'` :)

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, I have changed that now.

Comment: Actually, there is still something strange with it I think. I will work on that. But do you have any tips on creating the variables?

Comment: Your `for` loop only prints text, so what do you want to assign to `temp_class`?

Comment: you can use https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Yes @UnholySheep, I would like to assign the result of the loop to temp_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you goal is to get these `strings` into `temp_class` just append them instead of `print`

```
temperatures = [-5.4, 1.0, -1.3, -4.8, 3.9, 0.1, -4.4]

temp_class = []

for i in temperatures:
    if i < -2:
        temp_class.append('Cold')
    elif i >= -2 and i <= 2:
        temp_class.append('Slippery')
    elif i >2 and i < 15:
        temp_class.append('Comfortable')
    else:
        temp_class.append('Warm')

print(temp_class)
# ['Cold', 'Slippery', 'Slippery', 'Cold', 'Comfortable', 'Slippery', 'Cold']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and use it in your list comprehension:

```
temperatures = [-5.4, 1.0, -1.3, -4.8, 3.9, 0.1, -4.4]

def feeling(temp):
    if temp < -2:
        return 'Cold'
    elif -2 < temp <= 2:
        return 'Slippery'
    elif 2 < temp < 15:
        return 'Comfortable'
    else:
        return 'Warm' 

[feeling(temp) for temp in temperatures]
# ['Cold', 'Slippery', 'Slippery', 'Cold', 'Comfortable', 'Slippery', 'Cold']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map()

```
temperatures = [-5.4, 1.0, -1.3, -4.8, 3.9, 0.1, -4.4]

def get_temp_class(i):
    if i < -2:
        return 'Cold'
    elif i >= -2 and i <= 2:
        return 'Slippery'
    elif i >2 and i < 15:
        return 'Comfortable'
    else:
        return 'Warm'

temp_class = map(get_temp_class, temperatures)
```